# How to make spotless format your code as per custom config file which is followed by checkstyle in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spotless

My checkstyle is following custom config file define in root folder of application(config.xml file).
I am trying to identify how to configure spotless in gradle such that spotless shall aut format that code follwing rules defined in the same xml file

I am trying to get some help in the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.